# Atom does not allow me to use Space bar and delete button

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, atom-editor

In the Atom Editor i am not able to use the Space bar to insert a space and the delete button to delete characters. It works as a pointer and moves forward and backwards

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by having [vim-mode](https://github.com/atom/vim-mode) enabled, which will cause Atom to use the same behavior as Vi(m).

When you're not in *Insert Mode* in Vi(m), the Space and Backspace keys will simply move the cursor.

Please try one of the following:

- Enter Insert Mode by pressing the "i" key, then try the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar again.
- Or, disable the *vim-mode* package to use the regular Atom bindings, which will allow you to use Space for entering a space character.

Comment: freak :D i need to disable it. or is it a good thing to have it?

Comment: If you don't want to use the Vim bindings, you don't need it. Only keep it enabled if you absolutely need the Vim key bindings.